# req.user is undefined. React.js , Routes, Express , Passport

Tags: reactjs, routes, passport-local

I have tried to simplify my application to troubleshoot.  https://github.com/monochromaticmau/log-in

My problem is how to use this `req.user` throughout the webpage to see if the user is logged in so that I can limit certain features. My plan was to check `req.user` on each componentDidMount to see if the user is logged-in before enabling certain features on each page. `req.user` comes up as `undefined` after login and `GET` request right after in modal . When I test it with a REST Client it works properly( see image) and deserializes but it doesn't in the app example .   I'm MOST interested in the button on home page working and the button enabled in data page after login. It behaves similarly in my app.. `req.user` is `undefined` when I attempt a `GET` user request after login.

> username: x
>
> password: x

for testing.

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUw_TgRhTBE and that got me as far as I am now, but I don't know how to apply this login across all of my routes. I want to make sure user is logged-in to  open up certain features. I emulated this with a button that is disabled if you're not logged in.

How does one implement something like this? I thought passport handled this and kept a persistent session, that's how the `GET` request is (or should be) able to get `req.users` after a successful login `POST` request? Videos or articles would be great.

[image: Login Example]

[image: GET Request to see req.user on homepage]

[image: Button Enable after Login Success]

[image: Rest Client in Visual Studio Code Working]

Answer (score 0):

option 1 :
u can save the user data after login in a redux state and in the components u can check using `useEffect` if the redux state has some value or not and if it has values then u can use ?(ternary) operator to show the required contents. If ur not comfortable with redux then use Option2

option 2 :
After login is complete save the user data in local storage and in differennt components check in `useEffect` if local storage contains the required values or not and based on that render the required data in the page

for articles medium articles about redux with react are very good as redux is built for exactly what u want here. This is a good one
https://medium.com/@bretcameron/a-beginners-guide-to-redux-with-react-50309ae09a14

sry i dont have any code examples here but feel free to comment

Comment: I don't know redux , useEfftect or what saving in local storage entails. I will research all and follow-up. I thought passport handled this? Good for persistent session to see if a user is signed in?

Answer (score -1):

> My real problem is how to use this req.user throughout the webpage to see if the user is logged in so that I can limit certain features.

You've to make two components

**Public Route Component**, responsible for rendering all public routes of your react app and public components should be wrapped inside it

**Private Route Component**, responsible for rendering routes that should be authenticated where you can check `req.user` and all your private routes should be wrapped in it (so you can limit certain features based on the user logged in)

The basic idea of private route component is:

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  // if not logged in
  if (!req.user) {
    return 'You are not logged in'
  }

  // otherwise show private children components
  return props.children;
}
```

And then use this Private Route component to wrap all the routes that you want to be authenticated:

```
<PrivateRoute>
  <SuperSecretComponent />
</PrivateRoute>
```

Now `SuperSecretComponent` can only be accessed if the user is logged in. More [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-qdp-XBJg)

Comment: Being logged out, a user can still go to the route, it's just limited. When they sign in it will open up options (like the button being disabled if not logged in). I think what you are suggesting is preventing to enter the page entirely. Right?  That's not what I was looking for.